# Execution time Of the webpage

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to  get execution time of the remote webpage which is the time for  server needs to generate the webpage. I use nodejs.  how can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use console.time() and console.timeEnd()

```
console.time("exec-time");
/* some code to benchmark */
console.timeEnd("exec-time");
```

For more info https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_console_time_label

Answer (score 0):

Use `webpagetest` library.

You can read more about it [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpagetest)

I think this will work for you. Thanks.

Comment: Is there some free service?